Dimension of the global stable manifold for Lipstichz continuous dynamical system versus discontinuous dynamical systems
I would like to see how we can prove that the dimension of the 'global' stable manifold is equal to the dimension of the local stable manifold. In other words, if our Jacobian has 2 stable eigenvalues (real part strictly negative), we can conclude that the global stable manifold of this hyperbolic point is also of dimension 2. This is intuitive but surprisingly I had a counter example when the dynamical system is discontinuous.
For continuously differentiable vector fields, my intuition is that since the solutions are unique, the backward flow of the local stable manifold (which is the global stable manifold) should retain the same dimension (a line should stay a one dimensional curve). However, I would like to see how we rigoursly prove this.
Obviously for dicontinuous dynamical systems, this doesn't hold as the backward solutions are not unique so you can have a set of dimension 2 with trajectories converge locally to a line (1 dimension).
I hope that the math community can help me with this question.

and I am also interested to see the extension to singular points instead of hyperbolic equilibrium.
